# Fresco is not load to my App in Android studio

Tags: android, picasso, facebook-android-sdk, android-library, fresco

I installed Frescos's library as the website said
and I went to add

```
 <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
android:layout_width="130dp"
android:layout_height="130dp"
fresco:placeholderImage=""
/>
```

then it say com.facebook.drawee doesn't found
I put the library in build.gradle
and put `Fresco.initialize(this);` in Application class
[Image From My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xceyg.png)

Comment: Can you share Gradle file code?Sync the project once

Comment: [http://prntscr.com/hpk0nh]
this is img of my Gradle file

Comment: Can u share your application class code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

`compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.7.1'`

Instead of

`compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.7.0'`

It should work.`fresco` removed that class `SimpleDraweeView` in 1.7.1 they upgraded

See link https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1991